# How to temporarily Turn Off zscaler using Windows Command Line?

Tags: r, docker, cmd, automation, zscaler

I am trying to automate a docker command in R. However, in order to run the command, zscaler must be turned off for it to work.

The R script is as follows:

```
shell(cmd = "docker some command", shell = "CMD.EXE")
```

It creates an error because zscaler is on but works when it's off.

I would like to write a command that turns off zscaler before this R script and then another one after to turn it back on.  Is such a command possible?

Comment: bump, this would be helpful, I can turn it off manually, but it's easier to have it automated